# Как получить абзацы из docx в C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, office, docx

Есть word.docx документ в котором есть несколько абзацев (Или как там их по другому, параграфы). Мне нужно получить абзацы отдельно, и записать их куда то (пока не знаю куда лучше записать. Надеюсь и это вы подскажете).

Comment: Открыть файл в ворде и записать его в том формате, который нужен туда, куда нужно - не вариант?

Comment: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX

Comment: Можно использовать [OpenXML Power Tools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools). В этом случае получить параграфы можно как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43417213/3129992).